# How to save contacts on local ios device using swift language?

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I call my addContacts function(see code) in viewWillAppear.

What I want is that when I run the code, the values that I provided in firstName and lastName strings gets stored as a contact in the built-in iOS contacts app.

It is working in the simulator, but it isn't coming under the right section. For example if I pass "David" and "Ginger" as firstName and lastName strings, it adds the contact "David Ginger" in the app but it comes under '#' section, and not under "D" section(or even "G" section since by default sorting in contacts app is through surname). 
Moreover, it doesn't work at all on my iPhone. I even gave a button which will implement the function when clicked, but it doesn't work.

PS - I'm trying to develop an iOS in-built contacts app like application.

I searched a lot on the internet and considering what's mentioned on apple's developer website, my function is pretty much correct. I couldn't find anything helpful on the internet.

```
addContacts() {
        let store = CNContactStore()
        let storeMutable = CNMutableContact()
        storeMutable.namePrefix = firstName
        storeMutable.nameSuffix = lastName
        let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
        saveRequest.add(storeMutable, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
        try! store.execute(saveRequest)
}

//calling this function in viewWillAppear

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        fetchContacts()
        addContacts()
}
```

I want my app to save the contact permanently on the local device. Just like the built-in contacts app.

Comment: You need to use the family name not suffix like this:
 storeMutable.familyName = "yourlastName"

Answer (score 2):

> my function is pretty much correct

No, it isn’t. You have misunderstood the CNContact properties. Your contact has *no name;* therefore it is not sorted among contacts that *do* have a name. So start by giving it a name! Change

```
    storeMutable.namePrefix = firstName
    storeMutable.nameSuffix = lastName
```

To

```
    storeMutable.givenName = firstName
    storeMutable.familyName = lastName
```